# Sorting a file using max heap

Tags: java, sorting

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, I made a program that reads a file and sorts them by salary using a max heap but the output is coming out with them slightly sorted.

```
public static Employee[] employees = new Employee[6];
public static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("IDC");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Employernotes.txt"));
    int id = 0;
    String name = "";
    double salary = 0;
    String department = "";
    String position = "";
    int years = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        id = scan.nextInt();
        name = scan.next();

        salary = scan.nextDouble();
        department = scan.next();
        position = scan.next();

        years = scan.nextInt();

        employees[index] = new Employee(id, name, salary, department, position, years);
        index++;

    }

    for (int kk = employees.length - 1; kk >= 0; kk--) {
        heapM(employees, kk);
    }

    //PRINT
    for (int krk = 0; krk < employees.length; krk++) {
        System.out.println(employees[krk]);
    }
}

public static void heapM(Employee[] employees, int i) {

    int largest;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    if (((left < employees.length) && (employees[left].getSalary() > employees[i].getSalary()))) {
        largest = left;
    } else {
        largest = i;
    }

    if (((right < employees.length) && (employees[right].getSalary() > employees[largest].getSalary()))) {
        largest = right;
    }
    if (largest != i) {
        swap(i, largest);


        heapM(employees, largest);
    }
}

private static void swap(int i, int largest) {
    Employee t = employees[i];
    employees[i] = employees[largest];
    employees[largest] = t;

}
```

The output is:

```
Salary: 8000000.0
Salary: 85000.0
Salary: 290000.0
Salary: 10000.0
Salary: 48000.0
Salary: 32000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For heap sort, you need to do an initial heapify to setup the initial heap, then reheapify (with sift down) as you move each "largest" element to the end of the array. Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort